# Как передать данные с api из компонента React в другой компонент

Tags: reactjs, api, react-router

Я новичок в использовании API .У меня есть сервер API новостей на базе которого я сделала сайт. Новости выводятся на главной странице(название, автор и время). При клике на новость открывается страница самой новости(StoryPage.jsx), на которой должны отображаться название новости, автор и ссылка на нее. Я не понимаю как эти данные достать. Сервер разобрала в hnApi.js, Далее оттуда информация идет в StoryContainer.js, который в свою очередь передает данные в компонент Story.js. Я не знаю как быть с компонентом StoryPage.jsx, чтобы он выводил мне данные новости. Помогите пожалуйста!

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
import { getStory } from "../services/hnApi";
import { StoryWrapper, StoryTitle, StoryMeta, StoryMetaElement } from "../styles/StoryStyles";
import { mapTime } from "../mappers/mapTime";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { StoryPage } from "./StoryPage";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import AppContext from "./context";


export const Story=({storyId})=>{
    const [story, setStory]=useState({});
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        getStory(storyId).then(data=>data&&data.url&&setStory(data));
    },[]);
 return  story&&story.url?(
    <StoryWrapper data-testid="story"> 
       
        <StoryTitle>
        <Link to="/storyPage"><a href={story.url}>
       
            {story.title}</a></Link>
 </StoryTitle>


<StoryMeta>
    <span data-testid="story-by">
        <StoryMetaElement color="#000">By:</StoryMetaElement>{story.by}
    </span>
    <span data-testid="story-time">
        <StoryMetaElement color="#000">Posted:</StoryMetaElement>{` `}
        {mapTime(story.time)}
    </span>
 </StoryMeta>
 </StoryWrapper>
 ):null;


}
```

```
    import React,{useEffect,useState} from "react";
    import { getStoryIds } from "../services/hnApi";
    import { Story } from "../components/Story";
    import { GlobalStyle, StoriesContainerWrapper } from "../styles/StoriesContainerStyles";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

    export const StoriesContainer=()=>{
        const refreshPage=()=>{
            window.location.reload();
        }
        const [storyIds, setStoryIds]=useState([]);

        useEffect(()=>{
       getStoryIds().then(data=>setStoryIds(data));
    },[]);
        return (
        <>
        <GlobalStyle/>
        <StoriesContainerWrapper data-test-id="stories-container">
        <h1>Hacker News</h1> 
        <button type="button" onClick={refreshPage}>Refresh</button>
       {storyIds.map(storyId=>(
            <Story key={storyId} storyId={storyId}/>
        ))};
        </StoriesContainerWrapper>
        </>
    )
    }
```

````
  import axios from 'axios';
  import { selectFields } from '../selectors/SelectFields';

  export const baseUrl='https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/';
  export const newStoriesUrl=`${baseUrl}newstories.json`;
  export const storyUrl=`${baseUrl}item/`;

  export const getStory = async (storyId) => {
      const result=await axios
      .get(`${storyUrl+storyId}.json`)
      .then(({data})=>data && selectFields(data));
      return result;
  };

  export const getStoryIds = async () => {
      const result=await axios.get(newStoriesUrl).then(({data})=>data);
      return result;
  };```

```     //StoryPage.jsx

  import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
  import React from "react";
  import { Story } from "./Story";
  import { StoryWrapper, StoryTitle, StoryMeta, StoryMetaElement } from "../styles/StoryStyles";
  import { mapTime } from "../mappers/mapTime";
  import { getStoryIds } from "../services/hnApi";


  export const StoryPage=()=>{
   
      const [storyIds, setStoryIds]=React.useState([]);
      React.useEffect(()=>{
          getStoryIds().then(data=>setStoryIds(data));
      },[]);
      return  <>
      <Link to="/">
      <button>Container</button>
      </Link>
    <Story></Story></>
  }
````

Comment: Когда пользователь нажимает в компоненте на ссылку, что должно происходить? В компонент StoryPage должно передаваться что? В нем просто кроме кнопки для возврата ничего нет и смущает getStoryIds()... т.е. не очень понятно поведение, которое ожидаете

Comment: @SwaD
В StoryPage  должно передаться название новости, ссылка на новость, дата и автор.

Answer (score 0):

Мне полноценно проверить решение негде, но вот пример того, как это сделать через react-router-dom

В компоненте **Story** передаем в state всю сторю(story), которую вы получили от вашего API.

```
<StoryTitle>
    <Link to="/storyPage" state={story}>
        <a href={story.url}>
            {story.title}
        </a>
    </Link>
 </StoryTitle>
```

В компоненте **StoryPage** добавяем хук useLocation и в момент установки компонента в DOM записываем в состояние значение state. Далее останется написать сам рендер.

```
export const StoryPage=()=>{
    const location = useLocation();
    const [storyIds, setStoryIds]=React.useState([]);
      React.useEffect(()=>{
          //getStoryIds().then(data=>setStoryIds(data));
          setStoryIds(location.state);
      },[]);
      
      React.useEffect(()=>{
          console.log(storyIds);
      }, [storyIds])
      
      return  <>
      <Link to="/">
          <button>Container</button>
      </Link>
    <Story></Story></>
  }
```